# Python Regex Match sub-string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

`spf=pass (sender IP is 198.71.245.6)
 smtp.mailfrom=bounces.em.godaddy.com; domainname.com.au; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=godaddy.com;domainname.com.au; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=godaddy.com;`

With the following code:

```
if "Authentication-Results" in n:
    auth_results = n['Authentication-Results']
    print(auth_results)

    spf = re.match(r"spf=(\w+)", auth_results)
    if spf:
       spf_result = spf.group(1)

    dkim = re.match(r"^.*dkim=(\w+)", auth_results)
    print(dkim)
    if dkim:
        dkim_result = dkim.group(1)
```

The SPF always matches but the DKIM doesn't:

`print(dkim) = None`

According to the regex testers online it should: https://regex101.com/r/ZkVg74/1 any ideas why it's not i also tried these:

`dkim = re.match(r"dkim=(\w+)", auth_results)
dkim = re.match(r"^.*dkim=(\w+)", auth_results, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: is that string at the top all one string or a few different ones?

Comment: @HenryWoody, it's one strng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` does not match a newline character by default. Since the `dkim` in your test string is on the second line and your regex pattern tries to match any non-newline character from the beginning of the string with `^.*`, it would not find `dkim` on the second line. You should either use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to match a newline character:

```
dkim = re.match(r"^.*dkim=(\w+)", auth_results, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

or remove the unnecessary match from the beginning of the string altogether:

```
dkim = re.search(r"dkim=(\w+)", auth_results)
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the `re.DOTALL` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, [*re.match*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) works from the beginning. so your `r"dkim=(\w+)"` trial doesn't work.

Second, the `.` symbol matches characters except the new line character. If you want it to, you should explictly force it using `re.S` or [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag.

Also, you can use `[\s\S]` or `[\w\W]` to match any characters.

Try this:
`re.match(r"^[\s\S]*dkim=(\w+)", auth_results).group(1)`
or this:
`re.match(r"^.*dkim=(\w+)", auth_results, re.DOTALL).group(1)`